# Related List Master Detail Objects

Tags: page-layout, related-list

I have created custom object with Master Detail relationship to parent account object.

1) I have set the permission on the detail object to read view all for the user profiles

2) I have added the related list in the account page layout editor and saved it

3) When I select the account page layout view as the related list shows up

4) In the customize page link on account the related list is showing in the selected list pane

Now, when I go to any account the related list is not showing up, what I might be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted salesforce support. They provided me with great assistance. The problem is that I am not including the created date in related list as strange as it sounds but that was the problem.

here is a link for the above

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customizing_related_lists.htm&language=en_US

Thank you so much for your assistance pkumarlg

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the pagelayout of the account record and the modified pagelayout are same. Click on edit pagelayout from account layout.

Comment: Yes, I did so. I just don't know what the issue is? maybe its salesforce are having issues now abt this... its really frustrating a very simple procedure consuming such time. Thank you pkumarlg anyway